# How to create target areas in SVG/d3

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I am creating a d3 bar chart that has a tooltip that triggers over each bar. I also want to have the tooltip trigger when the mouse is above or below the the bar not just when the mouse is truly over it. It seems like it would be easiest to create a larger rectangle with zero opacity, and then programmatically trigger the rollover on the target element. What would the best way to do this?

Comment: What you describe is a reasonable approach. An alternate, more involved approach is to use a `mousemove`  handler on the parent container and detect which bar to highlight based on mouse position. Transparent nodes are considerably simpler to implement.

Comment: Check out this bl.ock: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3902569